# Does OkHttp have something easier similar to Unirest's field method for creating a RequestBody?

Tags: java, okhttp, unirest

Instead of `Unirest`, I'm using okhttp because there are responses where I only need the header so I don't need to download it using its `ResponseBody.string()` method.

I am however having a hard time building my requests for `POSTs` with a `RequestBody`. In `Unirest, you only need to use the`field`method to add to the its`RequestBody`:

```
Unirest.post(baseUrl + "/api/user")
                .header("Authorization", token)
                .field("id", id)
                .field("property", property)
                .asJson();
```

But in `OkHttp`, if I want to add a `RequestBody` I have to do this (in most cases where I don't really have a `json` lying around):

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
payload.put("user_id", userId);
payload.put("client_id", clientId); 
payload.put("type", status.getStatus());
payload.put("description", ""); 
payload.put("duration", 0); 

String requestBody = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload);

Call call = httpClient.newCall(
        new Request.Builder()

                .url(url) 
                .header("Authorization", tempToken)
                .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("application/json"), requestBody))
                .build()
);
```

I'm using a `Map` to create a `json` string because this is the easiest way for me to create a `json`.

Does `OkHttp` have something easier similar to `Unirest`'s `field` method for creating a RequestBody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `okhttp` has `FormBody` which has a `Builder`:

```
Call call = httpClient.newCall(
        new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Authorization", tempToken)
                .post(new FormBody.Builder()
                        // TODO user getId()
                        .add("id","")
                        .add("custom_fields", field)
                        .build())
                .build()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp doesn't have asJson. You can add a custom interceptor or implement a separate JSONObject.

Build JSON using JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("username", "yourEmail@com");
    jsonObject.put("password", "yourPassword");
    jsonObject.put("anyKey", "anyValue");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then call OkHttp like this:

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

The authors of okhttp use strings: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/PostExample.java